# Non-interactive api login after windows 10 update

Tags: vba, api, authentication, certificate, betfair

I was using this method to login to betfair api. Everything works fine, but after Windows 10 update (KB3140741) not working anymore. ResponseText = {"loginStatus":"CERT_AUTH_REQUIRED"} Anyone solved this?

Windows 10 Build 10586.218, version 1511
Microsoft Office 2016

```
Dim oHTTP As Object: Set oHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Dim uri As String: uri = "https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin"
oHTTP.Open "POST", uri, False
oHTTP.SetClientCertificate "Common Name"
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "X-Application", App_key
oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
oHTTP.send "username=" & UserName & "&password=" & Password & ""
```

Comment: Anyone else have any idea? Still without success on win 10

Answer (score 0):

I would try with `Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` instead :

```vb
Const uri = "https://identitysso.betfair.com/api/certlogin"

Dim req As Object
Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

req.Open "POST", uri, False
req.setOption 2, 13056          ' ignore all certificate errors '
req.setOption 3, "Common Name"  ' set the client certificate from the local store '
req.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.setRequestHeader "X-Application", App_key
req.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
req.send "username=" & UserName & "&password=" & Password & ""
```

Comment: I would like to keep a certificate login. Without certificate my method works too. On Windows 7 it works fine even with certificate login

Comment: It's also possible to set a client certificate with `Msxml2` with `.setOption 3, "certificate name"`

Comment: Same result as with `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1` It's weird, that before windows update, it works fine.